# How to set random gradient background color?

Tags: android

I have 3 gradient color in my drawable folder. i have to set these 3 colors randomly in recycle view items which i am getting from API. How to do it?

Comment: add some code snippet.

Comment: what do you want to acheive? @taru

Answer (score 0):

Declare global variables:

```
Random r = new Random();
int[] colors = new int[]{0xFF616261,0xFF131313, 0xFF125FF8};
```

Create GradientDrawable instance with randomly generated colors

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] {getRandom(random, colors), getRandom(random, colors)});
drawable.setCornerRadius(0f);
view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Code for random picking colors

```
private void getRandom(Random random, int[] colors) {
    return random.nextInt(colors.length);
}
```